Spacy/Torch fbgemm dependency
I'm trying to work with spacy to do some nlp in Python. Just for some background, I'm running on a windows PC with an Intel UHD Graphics card (So no cuda).
I tried installing the cpu form of pytorch with
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio as per the website, and I tried pip install spacy and pip install spacy==3.7 (So I've tried both versions). I'm running with Python version 3.12.5.
Whenever I try import spacy (or importing any nlp package for that matter), I keep getting the error:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local
\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfrs8p0\LocalCache
\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I've googled it and these packages should work together? Why am I missing this .dll file? I've also tried this on a different windows PC that does have an nvidia graphics card and cuda, same issue. Why is this file not being downloaded correctly?
Even manually downloading the file, I still get OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading ... shm.dll or one of its dependencies. What's going wrong here? Thanks.

This is a torch error:

the latest version of pyTorch is just missing .dll.

1st way is to uninstall the latest and reinstall the previous version by:
pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

then
pip install torch==2.3.0 torchvision==0.18.0 torchaudio==2.3.0

Once, the installation is successful then install spacy by:
pip install spacy


2nd way is to install .dll from here:
https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/libomp140_x86_64/00637fe34a6043031c9ae4c6cf0a891d/download
and place it in 'C:\Windows\System32'

3rd way is to add the missing dependency libomp140.x86_64.dll to the C:\Windows\System32 directory. To get this, we need to install the C++ build tools.
Complete description here:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/131662#issuecomment-2252589253

I tried these fixes and now I have:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading ... shm.dll or one of its dependencies.

I also tried installing even older versions of torch and it still didn't work.
